# Cannot Get C++ Function to Use String from User

Tags: c++, string, crash, char, cin

Please help.

I have this program from [here](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/md5-c-implementation/#comment-15516) that calls a function in a header file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "md5.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 string x;
 char* v_MD5String;
 MD5 md5 ;
 v_MD5String = "Hello World";
 x = puts(md5.digestString(v_MD5String));
 cout << x;
 return 0;}
```

The function called:

```
char* digestString( char *string ){
Init() ;
Update( (unsigned char*)string, strlen(string) ) ;
Final() ;
return digestChars ;}
```

The above works, however when I use input from the user it compiles, but the run crashes without any errors.

In the program, this is changed:

```
v_MD5String = "Hello World";
```

to this:

```
cin >> v_MD5String;
```

What should I do to get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: This is C++. Use `std::string`.

Comment: You are passing a `string literal` "Hello World" as an argument.  If any of those functions attempt to change that string literal, the behavior of your program is undefined.  Just the fact that you're casting in the `Update` function so as to "make the compiler shut up" is an indication of your attempt into trying to fool the compiler into thinking that string is modifiable.

Comment: Also, why is your parameter in the `digestString` function named `string`?  Wouldn't that be a little confusing?

Comment: It is not my code. I am using someone else's header code and modding there working program to take input from the user. The change to using user input is the part not working. Thanks.

Comment: to use `cin >> v_MD5String;` the variable should be allocated

Comment: If I would be on your place, I would live these "bugs" to the ovner to debug it, and just find some another tutorial. because this is the wrong way to learn C++.

Comment: @codekiddy: It's certainly the wrong way to learn C++, but at the very least it's a great way to learn about C++ software engineering in the Real World(tm), where you will often have to deal with bad code you have to use but cannot or are not allowed to modify :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you have the following function declared in a header file which you cannot modify:

```
char* digestString( char *string );
```

You should first know that this is questionable coding style. The function takes a `char *` rather than a `char const *`, which implies that the passed data is *changed*, yet it *also* returns something. I had to dig around in the implementation posted on the page you linked to find out that `string` is really an input parameter, so that the author just forgot about using `const` and the data is not going to be changed anyway.

*(The data not going to be modified is at least my **assumption** upon superficial code analysis and some compile tests. You should ask the author to be really sure!)*

If you use this function in C++, your first task should be to provide a safer, easy-to-understand wrapper function which uses real C++ strings (the `std::string` class), not C strings (which happen to be completely unencapsulated pointers to characters in memory, which is fine in the C world but not in C++). You already use one `std::string` in your program. That's good. Now use it more:

```
std::string SafeDigestString(MD5 &md5, std::string const &input)
{
    // the input of digestString will never be modified:
    return md5.digestString(const_cast<char *>(input.c_str()));
}
```

Both the `const &` and the parameter name make it clear that we are dealing with input.

Note that I used a `const_cast<char *>` to pass the `std::string`'s C-compatible data representation, which is `char const *`, to the `digestString` function. This is one of the **rare cases where a `const_cast` is appropriate**; it's also a typical one, namely making up for shortcomings with regards to `const` declarations in other code you have to use. If all functions in the `MD5` class correctly declared their input parameters `const`, then no `const_cast` would be needed.

Also note that I just prepend every `std` identifier with `std::`, rather than having `using namespace std`. This is often the better, simpler, more consistent choice.

---

Now that we have our safe C++ mechanism in place, `main` becomes drastically simpler:

```
int main()
{
    MD5 md5;
    std::string result = SafeDigestString(md5, "Hello World");
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

We have laid the base to implement user input, which is best done with the `std::getline` function:

```
int main()
{
    MD5 md5;
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::string result = SafeDigestString(md5, input);
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```